# How can I achieve more uniform backtracking in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Assuming I have:

```
makeTillDone(X) :- try(X).
makeTillDone(X1) :- changeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2).
makeTillDOne(X1) :- changeTwo(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2).
```

prolog will try to satisfy makeTillDone(X) in sequence:

```
try(X), 
ChangeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> try(X)
ChangeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> changeOne(X3, X4), makeTillDone(X4) -> try(X) 
etc
```

how can I achieve more uniform backtracking:

```
try(X), 
ChangeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> try(X)
ChangeTwo(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> try(X)
ChangeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> changeOne(X3, X4), makeTillDone(X4) -> try(X) 
changeOne(X1, X2), makeTillDone(X2) -> changeTwo(X3, X4), makeTillDone(X4) -> try(X) 
etc
```

Comment: You need to become consistent in the use of contants: Some of your predicates (`ChangeOne(X1, X2)`) have a functor that starts with a capital letter (thus the functor look like a variable instead of a constant): That's not allowed in base Prolog.

Comment: There are still some `ChangeOne/2` and `ChangeTwo/2` ...

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you are asking.

Your program is a representation of the following search tree (or proof tree).

[image: base tree]

...which is traversed in a leftmost-first, depthmost-first manner until a the root node has been proven true (constructively, so we get a valid value for `X`).

This is of course done recursively, essentially copying the base search tree into lower nodes (with suitable variable renaming, not done here):

[image: recursive tree]

The search order you seem to want is a bit more jumpy:

[image: maybe this tree?]

Possibly Breadth-First Search or better [Iterative Deepening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) is what you want.

However, this is not as straightforward as it might be as you cannot just change the search strategy of Prolog, but need to write a little interpreter: https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_3.html